# Convert a letter grade to a GPA: What is wrong with my code?

Tags: python-2.7, function, pandas

I have a dataframe, df, similar to the one below.

```
ID       SUBJ           GRADE

1   Amer Natl Govt      A
2   Princ Of Macroecon  B
3   General Biology     B
4   Concept Of Chem     C
5   General Chem        C
```

I’d just like to convert the letter grade (GRADE) to a grade-point average.

I’ve written the following code, which always returns the exception, 2.3 for all rows, as if the datatype of the letter in my list of tuples is of a different type than that in my dataframe, but they are both strings.  Could someone tell me the problem with my code? Thank you.

```
def getGradePoint(row):

    grades = [('A+', 4.0), ('A', 4.0), ('A-', 3.7), ('B+',3.3), ('B',3.0), ('B-',2.7), ('C+',2.3), ('C',2.0),\
          ('C-',1.7),('D+',1.3),('D',1.0),('D-',0.7),('F',0.0)]
    for i in range(len(grades)):
         if row == grades[i][0]:
             return grades[i][1]
         else:
             return 2.3

df['GRADE_PT'] = df['GRADE'].apply(getGradePoint)   

ID       SUBJ           GRADE    GPA

1   Amer Natl Govt      A        2.3
2   Princ Of Macroecon  B        2.3
3   General Biology     B        2.3
4   Concept Of Chem     C        2.3
5   General Chem        C        2.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that your loop will always return a result on the first iteration.  On the first iteration, you get `('A+', 4.0)` as the tuple, the `if` statement is `False` as the grade isn't `A+`, so the `else` statement gets evaluated and returns `2.3`.

Instead, return `2.3` only after the loop has completed:

```
def getGradePoint(row):
    grades = [('A+', 4.0), ('A', 4.0), ('A-', 3.7), ('B+',3.3), ('B',3.0), ('B-',2.7), ('C+',2.3), ('C',2.0), \
          ('C-',1.7),('D+',1.3),('D',1.0),('D-',0.7),('F',0.0)]
    for i in range(len(grades)):
        if row == grades[i][0]:
            return grades[i][1]

    return 2.3
```

However, as already noted, it is easier to just use a dictionary. Using your existing construction of `grades`:

```
grades = [('A+', 4.0), ('A', 4.0), ('A-', 3.7), ('B+',3.3), ('B',3.0), ('B-',2.7), ('C+',2.3), ('C',2.0),\
          ('C-',1.7),('D+',1.3),('D',1.0),('D-',0.7),('F',0.0)]
df['GRADE_PT'] = df['GRADE'].map(dict(grades))
```

Answer (score 3):

use a dictionary instead.

```
my_grad={'A': 4.0, 'B' : 3.0}

df['new_grades']=df.GRADE.map(my_grad)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest using a python dictionary to store the grade values. It would eliminate the need for a loop.

As for why it's not working, think about what your loop is doing. For each grade, it first checks if the grade is an 'A+', since that is the first entry in grades. Then, since it is not, it goes straight to the else statement and returns 2.3. Try having the else statement just print something or eliminating the else statement entirely. Just make sure you get rid of the return statement within the else.